# Help with Aggregate Query controller for a VF page using google charts

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts

I have written a controller with an aggregate query to use on a VF page with google charts. I have it mostly working, but the roll-up for the pie chart and the tables does not seem to be working.. can someone take a look and point me in the right direction? Thanks - here is a link to how it looks: http://mastercontrol.force.com/cetdashboard
I need the pie to only show the red/yellow/green. And the first table should show how many accounts fall into those categories, the 2nd table should show how many accounts are in each of those "types". The filters on the right should filter every chart.

Controller

```
    public class GroupforCET2{
    // Data class
    public class Data {
        public String name1 { get; set; }
        public Integer data1 { get; set; }
        public String name2 { get; set; }
        public Integer data2 { get; set; }
        public String name3 { get; set; }
        public Integer data3 { get; set; }
        public String name4 { get; set; }
        public Integer data4 { get; set; }
        public String name5 { get; set; }
        public Integer data5 { get; set; }
        public String name6 { get; set; }
        public Integer data6 { get; set; }
        public String name7 { get; set; }
        public Integer data7 { get; set; }
        public Integer data8 { get; set; }
        public String name9 { get; set; }

        public Data(String name1, Integer data1, String name2, Integer data2, String name3, 
                    Integer data3, String name4, Integer data4, String name5, Integer data5, String name6, 
                    Integer data6, String name7, Integer data7, Integer data8, String name9) {
            this.name1 = name1;
            this.data1 = data1;
            this.name2 = name2;
            this.data2 = data2;
            this.name3 = name3;            
            this.data3 = data3;
            this.name4 = name4;            
            this.data4 = data4;
            this.name5 = name5;            
            this.data5 = data5;
            this.name6 = name6;            
            this.data6 = data6;
            this.name7 = name7;            
            this.data7 = data7;
            this.data8 = data8;
            this.name9 = name9;
        }
    }
    public List<Data> getChartData(){
    List<AggregateResult> arList = [SELECT  Overall_Status_Picklist_for_Dashboards__c status ,COUNT(Final_NPS_ScoreCalc__c) cstatus,
                                    Subsidiary__c Subs, COUNT(MasterControl_Subsidiaries_FTE__c) cSubs, 
                                    Tier__c Tier, COUNT(Tier_calc__c) cTier,
                                    Target_Industry_Picklist__c Target,  COUNT(Target_Industry__c) cTarget, 
                                    Territory_Industry_Picklist__c Territory, COUNT(Territory__c) cTerritory, 
                                    Territory_Vertical__c Vertical, COUNT(Vertical__c) cVertical, 
                                    Sales_Channel_Picklist__c Channel, COUNT(Sales_Channel__c) cChannel,
                                    COUNT(Id) cAccounts, Account_Management_Type__c aType
                                    from Account
                                    Where Account_Management_Type__c != null
                                    group by Overall_Status_Picklist_for_Dashboards__c, 
                                    Subsidiary__c , Tier__c , Target_Industry_Picklist__c , Territory_Industry_Picklist__c , 
                                    Territory_Vertical__c , Sales_Channel_Picklist__c, Account_Management_Type__c ];
    List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : arList){       
        String Status = String.valueOf(ar.get('Status'));
        Integer cStatus = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cStatus'));
        String Subs = String.valueOf(ar.get('Subs'));
        Integer cSubs = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cSubs'));        
        String Tier = String.valueOf(ar.get('Tier'));
        Integer cTier = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cTier'));
        String Target = String.valueOf(ar.get('Target'));
        Integer cTarget = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cTarget'));
        String Territory = String.valueOf(ar.get('Territory'));
        Integer cTerritory = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cTerritory'));
        String Vertical = String.valueOf(ar.get('Vertical'));
        Integer cVertical = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cVertical'));
        String Channel = String.valueOf(ar.get('Channel'));
        Integer cChannel = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cChannel'));
        Integer cAccounts = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('cAccounts')); 
        String aType = String.valueOf(ar.get('aType'));
        dataList.add(new Data(Status, cStatus, Subs, cSubs, Tier, cTier, Target, cTarget,
                               Territory, cTerritory, Vertical, cVertical, Channel, cChannel, cAccounts, aType));
}



return dataList;

}}
```

VF Page

```
    <apex:page controller="GroupforCET2" sidebar="false" showheader="false">
        <apex:includeScript id="a" value="https://www.google.com/jsapi" />
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
          google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
        </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

          function drawVisualization() {
            var $dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Status', 'Accounts', 'Subsidiary',  'Tier', 'Target Industry', 
               'Territory', 'Vertical', 'Channel',  'Account Management Type'],

                <apex:repeat value="{!ChartData}" var="c">
                   ['{!c.name1}',{!c.data1},'{!c.name2}','{!c.name3}','{!c.name4}',
                '{!c.name5}','{!c.name6}','{!c.name7}', '{!c.name9}' ],
               </apex:repeat>
            ]);
      var $table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'chart1',
        'options': {
          'width': '300px'
        },
           'dataTable' : google.visualization.data.group($dataTable, [0],
      [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}])
    });  
    $table.draw();


      var $tableWrappers = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'chart2',
        'options': {
          'width': '300px'
        },
          'view': {'columns': [0, 1, 8]}
      });      
      var $acctable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'acctable',
        'options': {
          'width': '300px'
        },
           'dataTable' : google.visualization.data.group($dataTable, [8],
      [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}])
    });  
    $acctable.draw();        

      // Define a Pie chart
      var $pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
        'containerId': 'pieChart',
        'options': {
          'width': 300,
          'height': 300,
          'legend': 'none',
          'title': 'Overall Status',
            'is3D': 'true',
            'pieSliceTextStyle': {color: 'black'},
          'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
            'slices': [{color: 'green'}, {color: 'red'}, {color: 'yellow'}]

        },
     'dataTable' : google.visualization.data.group($dataTable, [0],
      [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}])
    });  

    $pieChart.draw();



      var $tableWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'tableWrapper',
        'options': {
          'width': '300px'
        },
          'view': {'columns': [0, 1, 8]}
      });

    var $subPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'sub_filter',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': '2',
        'useFormattedValue' : true,
        'ui': {
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': true,
          'labelStacking': 'vertical'
        }
      }      
    });

      var $tierPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'tier_filter',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': '3',
        'useFormattedValue' : true,
        'ui': {
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': true,
          'labelStacking': 'vertical'
        }
      }      
    });

      var $targetPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'target_filter',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': '4',
        'useFormattedValue' : true,
        'ui': {
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': true,
          'labelStacking': 'vertical'
        }
      }      
    });

    var $territoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'territory_filter',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': '5',
        'useFormattedValue' : true,
        'ui': {
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': true,
          'labelStacking': 'vertical'
        }
      }      
    });          

    var $verticalPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'vertical_filter',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': '6',
        'useFormattedValue' : true,
        'ui': {
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': true,
          'labelStacking': 'vertical'
        }
      }      
    });

    var $channelPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'channel_filter',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': '7',
        'useFormattedValue' : true,
        'ui': {
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': true,
          'labelStacking': 'vertical'
        }
      }      
    });

    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('table_dashboard')).
       bind([$subPicker,$tierPicker,$targetPicker,$territoryPicker,$verticalPicker,$channelPicker ], [ $tableWrapper,]).
       draw($dataTable) ;

    google.visualization.events.addListener($subPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $pieChart.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrapper.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $pieChart.draw();
    }); 



    google.visualization.events.addListener($tierPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $pieChart.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrapper.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $pieChart.draw();
    });          
    google.visualization.events.addListener($targetPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $pieChart.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrapper.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $pieChart.draw();
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener($territoryPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $pieChart.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrapper.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $pieChart.draw();
    });      

    google.visualization.events.addListener($verticalPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $pieChart.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrapper.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $pieChart.draw();
    });           

    google.visualization.events.addListener($channelPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $pieChart.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrapper.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $pieChart.draw();
    }); 

    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('table_dashboards')).
       bind([$subPicker,$tierPicker,$targetPicker,$territoryPicker,$verticalPicker,$channelPicker ], [ $tableWrappers,]).
       draw($dataTable) ;

    google.visualization.events.addListener($subPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $table.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $table.draw();
    }); 



    google.visualization.events.addListener($tierPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $table.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $table.draw();
    });          
    google.visualization.events.addListener($targetPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $table.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $table.draw();
    }); 

    google.visualization.events.addListener($territoryPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $table.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $table.draw();
    });     

    google.visualization.events.addListener($verticalPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $table.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $table.draw();
    });       

    google.visualization.events.addListener($channelPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $table.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [0],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $table.draw();
    }); 

    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('table_dashboards')).
       bind([$subPicker,$tierPicker,$targetPicker,$territoryPicker,$verticalPicker,$channelPicker ], [ $tableWrappers,]).
       draw($dataTable) ;

    google.visualization.events.addListener($subPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $acctable.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [8],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $acctable.draw();
    }); 



    google.visualization.events.addListener($tierPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $acctable.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [8],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $acctable.draw();
    }); 
    google.visualization.events.addListener($targetPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $acctable.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [8],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $acctable.draw();
    }); 

    google.visualization.events.addListener($territoryPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $acctable.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [8],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $acctable.draw();
    }); 

    google.visualization.events.addListener($verticalPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $acctable.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [8],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $acctable.draw();
    });    

    google.visualization.events.addListener($channelPicker, 'statechange',
    function(event) {
      // group the data of the filtered table and set the result in the pie chart.
      $acctable.setDataTable( google.visualization.data.group(
        // get the filtered results
        $tableWrappers.getDataTable(),
        [8],
        [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
      ));
      // redraw the pie chart to reflect changes
      $acctable.draw();
    }); 

         }







          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

            </script>
        </head>
        <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
            <div id="wrapperHeader">
                <center>
                    <div id="header">
                        <img src="https://c.na13.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015a0000002WenZ&oid=00D3000000003Hx&lastMod=1375828250000" alt="logo" />
                        <center>
                            <font size="3">
                                <a href="">OverView</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            |&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a href="">List View</a>
                            </font>
                        </center>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <table>
                <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
                    <td style='width: 200px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
                        <div id="sub_filter"></div>
                        <div id="tier_filter"></div>
                        <div id="target_filter"></div>
                        <div id="territory_filter"></div>
                        <div id="vertical_filter"></div>
                        <div id="channel_filter"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        <div  id="pieChart"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="table_dashboards">
                            <table>
                                <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
                                    <td >
                                        <div  id="chart1"></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="display:none;">
                                        <div  id="chart2"></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td >
                                        <div  id="acctable"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="table_dashboard">
                            <table>
                                <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
                                    <td style="display:none;">
                                        <div  id="tableWrapper"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Merry, after just taking a quick look, I suspect your problem is that your group bys are not done using `COUNT(field_name)` as opposed to the the way you have it set now with just `field_name`. Either that or you're not grabbing the `COUNT(field_name)` when creating your lists that your controller is binding to your VF page. I'm not able to study your code at the moment to really dig into further, but that's where I'd look. Either there or look at the design of your query and consider using a `Group by Cube`.

Comment: Which are the fields responsible for red/green/yellow in query and their count?

Comment: Overall_Status_Picklist_for_Dashboards__c & Final_NPS_ScoreCalc__c.